# Blender Cycles Rendering Speed

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I want to render scenes and things faster on my computer but I want it to be good quality as well. I set the sampling to around 200 samples and it takes so long to render just one scene on my computer (around a whole day for a couple seconds scene). Are there any upgrades I should add to my computer and if so please let me know. I have a AMD FX-6300 Six Core Processor, 8.0GB RAM, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti and 1 terabyte hardrive. I enabled GPU rendering properly as well but it takes forever to render a whole scene. My computer is around 9 months old.[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about blender, it is asking for a hardware recommendation.

Comment: It is about blender cycles rendering speed. Blender settings involve a graphics processor even for NVIDIA. I was just wondering if my hardware may be the case and if it would suffice and if I need to change any rendering settings.

Comment: Blender.org recommends a few setups including _recommended_ and _production grade_. [blender.org/.../requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) - but we avoid recommending specific brands. There are two parts to getting decent render speeds: 1) hardware 2) scene optimizations (depends on the scene..can include material tweaking, baking, compositor, render layers. ). Also consider [renderfarms](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15365/47)

Comment: I have heard of renderfarm before but for some reason whenever I go to their site it never displays the webpage and says it is not available.

Comment: @AustinH. There are many different renderfarms.. The post zeffi linked lists several blender-oriented services. (e.g. [sheepit](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com), a free distributed service)

Comment: Do you have to enable an addon in blender for sheepit? Like with renderfarm.fi?

Comment: @AustinH. Nope. Their website should explain how to use it: https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/faq.php#howdoesitwork